# Contribute a diagram to a package author?

Tags: fonts, packages

Well, this turned out to be a completely different question than the one I started writing!

Originally I was wondering how to make a version of `\textit` (and a parallel version of `\textsl`) that automatically tracks the nesting level and toggles on/off based on the oddness/evenness of the nesting depth.  `\emph` of course does this, but it isn't guaranteed to render in italics, and there doesn't seem to be a corresponding slant version of `\emph` for slant.

And then I discovered the `slemph` package, which provides exactly what I want.  Sometimes, while formulating a question, one thinks of better search terms/phrases and is better able to find the answer!

Anyway, I figured that a picture would be the best way to ask my question (originally), so I started out by making this drawing, which describes fictional macros `\RM`, `\IT`, `\SL`, and `\BF` which behave well together like `\textit`, `\textsl`, `\textbf`, etc.:

[image]

And then I made this, which demonstrates the inner workings of the decision-making that I was hoping to hack together:

[image]

But again, it turns out that `\textitswitch` and `\textslswitch` of package `slemph` already do exactly what I want, and I basically wasted my time making the diagrams.  But I did learn some new things.  :-)

So, as long as I have these diagrams (and the accompanying LaTeX source), I'm wondering if there is a preferred way to submit things to package authors for their consideration.  Is it acceptable to just e-mail them?  Or is there a more formal gateway through CTAN?  This particular package hasn't been updated in 13 years.

I would definitely find a diagram like this helpful in the documentation for the package.  I actually came across the package halfway through my investigation, but brushed it aside carelessly because I didn't realize from the description that it actually did what I wanted!  A picture like this would have led me to see it immediately.

Comment: 1) These diagrams are awesome. 2) This question has been asked and answered on [meta], but I don't quite remember why on meta: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-contact-a-package-author. 3) You could still ask a question about your initial problem, just to share the knowledge. Cf. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away. 4) Perhaps you could even make up a question to share the source of your diagrams? `;)`

Comment: I upvoted this to cancel the automatic "not a real question"  downvote.